# How do I start programming for GMOD (A sandbox game that uses Lua scripting)

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

I'm very new to the site and I understand that this is a really stupid question. I want to be as nice as possible and everything, but, how do I, someone who never coded in my life start making mods? How do I approach scripting in lua when there aren't that many sources for learning, and looking at already made code just makes my head blow up. How do I approach things, how do I learn them, just in general, how to anything related to programming. I'm very sorry if this is very newbie-like and basic and has been seen thousands of times. I really have a passion to get into modding, to get into animating,modelling, all that game design stuff. I have nearly all the tools I need, I just need to get into it. My hope is to make many mods and get people to enjoy games a little diffrently, I get that this will be a long trip, but I'm fully commiting into it.

Comment: Start through basic tutorials and slowly build up. Stat by learning Lua and understanding how it works. Build a simple mod or game. Do not get too ambitious at first. Get over the frustration when things fail. Keep trying. Enjoy the magic when you win small victories. Good luck!

Comment: The question was closed but nobody explained why. Stack-Overflow is meant for very specific technical questions that can be answered objectively. For questions like this one, a better place would be the `r/lua` subreddit or the discord server :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome! Glad to hear you've decided to learn coding! Generally speaking things can get very complicated very quickly. I would start by looking at some very basic programming tutorials on youtube. Your first goal should be to show the text "Hello World" in your language of choice
This is the documentation on getting started with Lua scripting, including a small tutorial about "Hello world".
https://www.lua.org/pil/1.html

Lua might not be the best language to start with, I would recommend picking up an easier language just to learn the basics of programming like python. It will definitely help with your head hurting from looking at code!

Coding in general is a huge and complex subject with tons of information. Never be afraid to google search for something you don't know the answer to.

Best of luck! I would recommend codewars.com as a good beginner place to learn basic coding syntax. Don't be afraid to google the answers, everyone has to start somewhere.

Comment: I don't think that Python is an easier language to learn than Lua; in fact, I think that it is the other way around. But there are more resources available for Python.

Comment: Thank you! The reason I choose lua is cause I need it for my own sake, cause it fits my interests. I heard many people say that C# is the best language to learn, and that lua takes a really long time to learn, but I think that I could really do alot, but I fear the limitations of the Source engine, cause I really dont know if I can do everything I want to do,so I really fear that I would just end up wasting time learning lua, when I can't do everything I wanted to do with it.

Comment: Half of the battle when learning programming for the first time is simply learning how to ask the right questions. Start with VERY basic problems. Get some text to display! Gradually over time do harder and harder projects. You wont waste your time learning lua, because the knowledge of programming you gain will transfer to other languages. Learning how to ask a programming question  and what questions you need to ask will take you far :)

Comment: @Segra_rules -- there is no single language that is the best to learn; if you keep programming, you will need to learn at least a few languages. The best language to start with is one that lets you do something that you want to do; if scripting in Lua lets you make mods, and if that is something that you want to do, then Lua is a good language for you to start with. What you learn in Lua will translate to many other languages. There will of course be differences; conventional wisdom is that the _second_ language that you learn is hardest, because you have to unlearn the first one.

Comment: Lua in games is more like a macro language and is depending on game engine version of Lua and functions or objects.